# regular languages with concatenations

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, formal-languages

the regular languages are closed under the operation:

init(L) = the set of the strings w such that for some x, wx is in L.

EDIT :
   x can be any string, a character or empty string
How can I prove that ?

Comment: It's been a while... but can `x` be the empty character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, misread the quesion on the first time, now I get it. It still trivial. Looking at the automate what you searching is a partion of the automate into two state sets S1 and S2, so that just one transition is between them (and if its from S1->S2 S1 contains of course the start node, and S2 the end node). Such exist always (exception empty language), in case there is no such node you can add one, so w is just a set containing the empty word, which is of course also regular (as well as the empty language case).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, the answer is that you can't.  Because it's not true.

First, let's consider the language `L = {aa, bb, cc}` and alphabet `{a, b, c}`

So, `init(L) = {a, b, c}`.  However, each of the elemnts in `init(L)` are not in `L`.

Edit: If we are concatenating empty characters, then `init(L) = {a, b, c, aa, bb, cc}`.  Which is still not equal to `L`.

Comment: The OP does not need init(L) to be L again, just to be it a regular language for the regular languages to be closed under init(.). Compare that the integers are closed under negation (i.e -a is integer for every integer a), yet -2 != 2.

Answer (score 0):

A language is regular iff there's a finite-state automaton that recognizes it. So, suppose L is a regular language and let A be an automaton that recognizes it. Now, say that a state of A is "good" if there's some set of possible transitions starting there and ending in the "accept" state. Define a new automaton A' in which all transitions to "good" states are replaced by direct transitions to the accept state. Then the language recognized by A' is exactly init(L).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a new DFA B, that makes all the state of A(the original DFA) that can reach to the final states of A the final state of B.